# What's a good way to describe algorithms without listing them?

Tags: algorithms, best-practices

Suppose there's some algorithm, piece of software code, or even a physical device computing a function, which I want to describe but **not** to list it or go into the details of its inner workings (so, I don't need something like `algorithm2e`, `algorithmic` and friends). What I do want to list is the name, the parameters, their data types, which of them are in, out, or in-out, what their relative lengths might be, default values, return value, exceptional conditions or input requirements and perhaps some more information. In a sense, something a bit similar to doxygen - but not generated from comments on source code.

How should I go about this? Just design something myself? Is there some package which is close enough to actually doing this?

**Note:** This is not about drawing diagrams. No nodes or arrows involved.

Comment: @Bobyandbob: But I don't want to display algorithms.

Comment: Okay i understand. Does Claudio Fiandrino answer to this maybe more related question: [Drawing a collaboration graph or tree with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51693/124842) help?

Comment: @Bobyandbob: No, that's not related to what I'm asking.

Comment: Using a Nassi-Schneider-Diagram, perhaps?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Has nothing to do with diagrams. Purely textual.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Those are not about what I'm trying to do. Nothing graphical here.